# How to store an Int32 into an ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an ArrayBuffer that may vary in length, depending on its content, so I'll need to continuously read and write different data types from various indices in the Array. Is there a way to do that without constructing a new typed array each time?

I've tried reading and writing from this ArrayBuffer by constructing new typed arrays for each value, but profiling my code reveals a lot of overhead using this approach.

```
const myArray = new ArrayBuffer(0x800) // populated from elsewhere
const readInt32 = (array, index) => {
  const typedArray = new Uint32Array(array, index, 1)
  return typedArray[0]
}
const writeInt32 = (array, index, value) => {
  const typedArray = new Uint32Array(array, index, 1)
  typedArray[0] = value
}

const sourceAddress = readInt32(myArray, 0)
const targetAddress = readInt32(myArray, 4)
const value = readInt32(myArray, sourceAddress)
writeInt32(myArray, targetAddress, value + 1)
```

This works, technically, but there's too much overhead for the amount of reading and writing I'm doing. Is there a better way to implement `readInt32` and `writeInt32`?